# Woocommerce - Price of an item by it's measurement

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, measurement

## Hi,

I want to create a website for selling custom paint.
The price depend on the size of the paint. It Depend on the width and the height. You can see what the price list look like. I want the price to be given automatically depend of the measurement the client enter on the website. Also, you can see on the picture what I want to look like on the website. So the price will depend on the width and the height.

## Exemple:

If the client enter 24  X 36 price will automatically show 375.

If he enter 25 X 36 it will be 420 because 25 is more then 24.

Thank you for your help

[Picture - Exemple of price list and measurement on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Fp4u.jpg)

Comment: [Measurement Price Calculator](http://www.skyverge.com/product/woocommerce-measurement-price-calculator/)

Comment: I ask on the plugin ''Measurement Price Calculator'' and they said that the plugin is not created for that. After that, I pass 3 hours on google and YouTube trying to find if anyone already have this question and I can't find anything... You can go on the website http://www.blinds-2go.co.uk/wooden-blinds/8266/satin-pure-white.html and you will see exactly what i'm trying to do they working the same way as I'm looking for.  Thank you